# Insert space until column

Tags: emacs

I have to enter in the following format...

```
A          B          C
D          E          F
[]
```

I use indent-relative to jump from one column to another. 
But is there a way to jump to column number? And if so, is there a way to insert spaces until that column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe `indent-to-column` would work for you.

```
indent-to-column is an alias for `indent-to'.

(indent-to-column COLUMN &optional MINIMUM)

Indent from point with tabs and spaces until COLUMN is reached.
Optional second argument MINIMUM says always do at least MINIMUM spaces
even if that goes past COLUMN; by default, MINIMUM is zero.

The return value is COLUMN.
```

It enters tabs too, but you can clean those up when you're done with the `untabify` command.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `move-to-tab-stop` with a custom `tab-stop-list` variable to denote your columns. You could use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `edit-tab-stops` <kbd>RET</kbd> to configure this variable in a visual manner.

You can also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ruler-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ruler-mode-toggle-show-tab-stops` <kbd>RET</kbd> to view your tab stops.

For jumping multiple columns, `move-to-tab-stop` doesn't repeat with a prefix arg, but if you define a keyboard macro which calls it, you can then use the prefx arg to repeat it as many times as you require:

Record macro:
<kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `move-to-tab-stop` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>

Either bind to key temporarily:
<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> (key)

Or name it and ask Emacs to provide you with the elisp to put in your init file:
<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> (name) <kbd>RET</kbd>
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> (name) <kbd>RET</kbd>
`(global-set-key (kbd "key") 'name)` (for the appropriate *key* and *name*)

You can enter a numeric prefix arg with any of:
<kbd>C-u</kbd> number(s)
<kbd>M-</kbd> number(s)
<kbd>C-</kbd> number(s)

e.g. if you had bound the macro to <kbd>C-i</kbd> then <kbd>M-4</kbd> <kbd>M-2</kbd> <kbd>C-i</kbd> would move forward forty two tab stops, and so would <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>C-i</kbd>

Set the `indent-tabs-mode` variable to `nil` to prevent tabs being inserted.

Comment: I've changed that from `tab-to-tab-stop` to the more appropriate `move-to-tab-stop`, which only inserts new white space if it needs to.